# How to design and store life cycle or states for a Java entity bean?

Tags: design-patterns, data-modeling

In our application, we have a pojo mapped to some entity. One pojo refers to one entry in DB. There are multiple steps for it's life-cycle. It gets created freshly, it goes 'live', after some calculations it either gets disabled or goes 'live' for something like plan B processing and then finally ends it's journey.

Problem comes, when sometimes business team asks some business related questions related to some data in DB. I have to run some queries and provide them data.

Can I implement some feature which takes entity id and returns it's entire life-cycle till the moment, or what steps it has gone through, so I can show it in UI, all they need is to put ID. We use Redis for caching, so one crude way is to put entries in Redis for each time saving in DB and query when required. The problem is that next time, for a new 'step' in life-cycle, a new person might forget to put entry in Redis.

Is there any good example of life-cycle management of entity in java? That would help me designing the structure in optimal way.

Comment: It sounds to me like your POJOs have too many responsibilities.  Is this a possible candidate for the Memento pattern?

Comment: Mostly it has id, a json body as of now. Body keeps changing, but that is not the concern. I'll look into memento pattern for it's eligibility. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Event Sourcing](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html). It's similar to the memento pattern Robert Harvey mentioned but instead of snapshots you work with lists of change events.

Actually implementing event sourcing might be too much for your use case (that's for you to analyze), but might help you to borrow some ideas from there.